# Executing cut command on ASCII text

Tags: command-line, scripts, sh

I have a text file written in the following way :

```
/home/walter197/file_created.txt
/home/walter197/myfile1
/home/walter197/new.txt
/home/walter197/sdl.tar.gz
/home/walter197/sys_info.html
/home/walter197/test2.sh
```

I wrote the following shell script to read each line of the file text , cut the fourth column  (which is the last column ) and write it to a new file:

```
#!/bin/bash 

path="/home/walter197/info.txt" 
new_file="/home/walter197/new_info.txt"

while IFS= read -r line
do 
    cut -d "/" -f 4 "$line" | cat $new_file

done < "$path"

exit
```

When i execute `cat new_file.txt` I got horrible weird texts .

So how can i fix the script so i can get the following in the new file:

```
file_created.txt
myfile1
new.txt 
sdl.tar.gz
sus_info.html
test2.sh
```

Comment: You *really* don't need a shell loop here at all - just `cut -d/ -f4 < "$path" > "$new_file"` or `cut -d/ -f4 "$path" > "$new_file"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change a couple of things:

```sh
#!/bin/bash 

path="/home/walter197/info.txt" 
new_file="/home/walter197/new_info.txt"

while IFS= read -r line
do 
    echo "$line" | cut -d "/" -f 4 >> $new_file

done < "$path"

exit
```